# Connecting android game with website to show user scores on logon

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, android-studio

How do I make my android game users logon to my website to see their scores? I can create fb login in app and website, but I need to show the score of the particular user in the website.

An example: A user opens my game,sees a login page(saves data online) or sign in as guest(saves data locally), plays sometime. If user goes to my website using the login, they should see their scores there.
This should be achievable by using Google play services. How do I make the user login to my website using google play login?. Is that even possible?

Comment: Hi. Please read [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Asking for links to tutorials doesn't really fit the Q&A format of this site. So either reformulate your question to address a specific problem you have while implementing the described feature or ask your question in a forum like https://www.gamedev.net/

Comment: Hi., Thanks for pointing out. Have edited the question to a specific part. and removed the need for tutorial link.